# jquery plugin get option from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating a jquery plugin. I want to get data from back end and send as options to the plugin.

```
  function getData(){
     $.when(http_get('../list/')).then(function(response){
        students = response;
        return students;
        console.log(response);
     }, function(response){
        console.log('get failed');
     })
  }
  $('#element').pluginSmart({
    data: getData()
  });
```

Here I am getting the data from backend but it is not assigned to the data option of the plugin.

I know the data is assigned before the ajax returns. How to wait till the ajax returns and then assign?

I want to keep it plugin initialization simple. otherwise I would have initiated the plugin inside the then function.

Comment: ajax is async and anyway your getData() method returns nothing

Comment: Any other way i can set remote data to plugin option?

Comment: call the ajax from within the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the data *before* initializing the plugin. Put your initialization code in the callback for your AJAX request, for example like this:

```
$.get('../list/', function(response){
    students = response;
    console.log(response);
    $('#element').pluginSmart({
        data: students;
    }); 
}).fail({
    console.log('get failed');
});
```

Alternatively, you can perform a synchronous request but that's horrible practice (see: [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re))

Comment: Like i said this plugin should be initialized as simple as possible. So i cant use it inside another ajax call.

Comment: "simple" is a subjective measure. I do not think that there is anything complicated in this approach. In any case, I am glad that you managed to resolve your problem.

Comment: I want to publish my work as plugin. So I want to make sure that non programmers can use this in ease.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way of handling this situation. Since my goal is to keep the plugin initialization simple. I just pass the url into the plugin and get the data from inside the plugin.